# Using Html and CSS directly in Wordpress page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I finished working on a html page but
when I try and add a new page to the Word press site. I paste a small amount of CSS style code for a 3d rotate. The Wordpress page creator tool removes the code. I have just pasted.

Here is the code in question just in case there is a specific problem related to my CSS.

```
<style>
}#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 450px;
  height: 281px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
  perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin-Y: 180deg;

  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
  -moz-transform-origin: 180deg;

}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aaa;
}


</style>
```

I am not sure why Word press is removing the code. Is there a way I can link a html file onto the page and make it display that snippet of html code.

I have read through pasts of the codex but I cannot find a section which relates to this specific need.

Comment: You should probably put this into a child theme. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Do you save it in the html editor?

Comment: That was such an obvious thing I forgot todo it. I was previewing it without the draft saved many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `}` in starting of style.

This may cause issue :

```
<style>
}
```

Please remove bracket and let me know

Comment: I have tried that and the same problem, and the WP also wants to remove the formatting I have put under the containers on the 3d pictures. But thanks for the suggestion it was bad practice my me.